# Android Studio error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this error when I open Android Studio and

1. I have try `.gradle` deleting and and re-installing it, it is not Working
2. I have also Download Latest Version of Android Studio
3. I have Provided Use Local Repository option trick that is also not working
4. and i have also Downloaded Google Repository

Here it is The error:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic Functionality (e.g: editing, debugging) will not work properly
>       Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>       This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>       For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>       Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>       Please read below process output to find out more:
>       -----------------------
>       Error occurred during initialization of VM
>       Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>       Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>       Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this : [Complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760855/3484762)

Step 1 : Open gradle.properties file in your Android Studio project.

Step 2 : Add this line at the end of the file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```